# How do I test uTP ports against DPI filtering?

Tags: bittorrent, nmap

How exactly does one test an [uTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol) port to see if it's firewalled? I can't seem to find any documentation on how [uTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol) is supposed to work, and nmap doesn't seem to have an [uTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol) option.

Comment: It's UTP all uppercase. You could try to connect to a UTP port.

Comment: @barlop I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @SoniEx2 You're coming across as very aggressive - in this and your other post. If you'd like people to help, then it may be worth taking time to consider their input and respond nicely...

Comment: Have you looked at the [`utp_test`](https://github.com/andradeandrey/GoUTP/tree/master/libutp/utp_test) application? Mentioned in the `libutp` documentation from Encombe's answer.

Comment: @Attie when I ask questions I expect to not have to do all the research for others. I assume they already know or are willing to learn about what I'm talking about. I'm looking at utp_test now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**u**Torrent **T**ransport **P**rotocol - **uTP** is a transport protocol layered on top of **UDP**.
So if there is a open **uTP** port, there is a open **UDP** port.
[spec.](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html)
[libutp](https://github.com/bittorrent/libutp)

Comment: There's this thing called DPI that could affect readings. UDP could test fine but uTP could be blocked.

Comment: Testing if ports are open, or testing if a connection is throttled or blocked, is two very different things and the former can't be done with nmap.